# LINQ - SelectMany with Strongly-typed DataSets

Tags: strongly-typed-dataset, linq

I have the following query that returns exactly what I need,

```
var dataRows = 
            (from headerLocationRow in headerLocationDataTable
             select WellsDao.Instance.GetAllWellData(headerLocationRow.HEADER_ID).WELL_BORE_CONSOLIDATED)
             .SelectMany(x => x.Select());
```

but I don't like how it mixes the inline query with extension methods.  This is for an older project, so I'm stuck with strongly-typed DataSets.  I tried to use two *from* statements, but it didn't like that.  **headerLocationDataTable** is a strongly-typed DataTable.  That **WellsDao.Instance.Get**... nonsense traverses the DataSet and returns a collection of DataTables strongly-typed as **WELL_BORE_CONSOLIDATED** based on the **HEADER_ID** field in the **headerLocationDataTable**.

This isn't a huge deal because the query works, but I'm really trying to get a handle on LINQ, so I just want to know how to do this whole thing as inline.  Or if you know of a more elegant way of writing this, please share. Ultimately, I want to get back a flat list of DataRows that contains all of the **WELL_BORE_CONSOLIDATED** rows, regardless of which parent **headerLocationRow** they are associated with.

Comment: What does `WellsDao.Instance.GetAllWellData(headerLocationRow.HEADER_ID)`?

Comment: It creates a data set for a parent record (in this case, a well) with the id matching HEADER_ID.  There are a lot of child tables for that parent, including WELL_BORE_CONSOLIDATED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
var dataRows =  from headerLocationRow in headerLocationDataTable
                from wbcRow in WellsDao.Instance.GetAllWellData(headerLocationRow.HEADER_ID).WELL_BORE_CONSOLIDATED
                select wbcRow;
```

It's the query syntax of a `SelectMany`.

Comment: Of course I'm going to say that I thought I tried that.  But obviously I was doing something wrong.  This is perfect.  It also returns the strongly-typed data row.  With my crappy query, I had to cast it afterwards.  Thank you!